# Conditional formatting won't work if the content of the cell is a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I've applied a custom formula conditional formatting that highlights the cell in column C if it matches with column K.

The formula I used is **=MATCH(C3,$K$3:$K$988,0)**. However, it does not highlight if the content of the cell is a formula (the formula on the cell is **=if(isblank(A47),"",C46+1)**).here is a screenshot of the sheet with the formula 
[image].

I tried typing the number manually, and it works, but won't work if it is a formula. If I type it manually, the format should be PLAIN TEXT so the conditional formatting will work. I tried to put in it AUTOMATIC, it does not work. Here is a screenshot of the sheet if I type the number manually 
[image].

I'm not sure why this is happening because it works well in other sheets with the same formula. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Share the sample please

Comment: Try to reset values format of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Adding one to C46 produces a number. If the values in column K are formatted as text it won't match with them. If you want to keep the numbers in column K formatted as text, you need to convert the number you're looking up to text before doing the lookup. You can use

```
MATCH(text(C3,"@"),$K$3:$K$988,0)
```

or just

```
MATCH(C3&"",$K$3:$K$988,0)
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely worked!! In column K, I used the formula =MATCH(K3,$C$3:$C$1059,0) so it will also highlight if it matches with column C, but it doesn't. The same case with what I posted. It only highlights if it was typed manually... Btw, the formula i used in column K is =RIGHT(J38,7).